# System freeze with dual screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I connected external monitor by USB Type-C. After that system freezes randomly. Only hard reset can help. Syslog shows:

```
Jan 31 10:13:59 AcerAspire kernel: [ 412.819175] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR flip_done timed out
Jan 31 10:13:59 AcerAspire kernel: [ 412.819191] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR [CRTC:131:pipe B] commit wait timed out
```

NVidia RTX 3050 Ti Mobile. Nvidia Driver version: 545.23.08.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Based on that log, a hard reset shouldn't be necessary and you can SSH in. Then you could reset almost everything by killing all graphical apps, unbinding the GPU from the console, unloading the GPU driver, and reloading it, but this is repair not prevention. Otherwise the only fix I can think of is changing the driver version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the fix was to disable secure boot. In addition to your flip_done error, I also saw this in the syslog:

```
[   27.011771] [drm:nv_drm_
master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab
 modeset ownership
```

After some research, I saw that the drm error could be an nvidia driver issue caused by secure boot. I disabled secure boot and haven't had any freezes since.

Comment: I already disabled the secure boot and my laptop still freezing. But thank you for your information

Comment: One other thing you could try is to set the Nvidia PRIME Profile to performance mode instead of on-demand mode. Based on my research, the flip_done error is a problem with with the integrated Intel Graphics, and performance mode uses the Nvidia GPU for most or all graphics purposes.